# Decompiling and recompiling APK file

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, dex, decompiler

I'm currently working on analyzing some android malwares and i need to decompile APK files. Reading an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12370973/5199226) and many other answers like it, i know that we can extract java source code and other resources, create a new project and put those files in, make some modifications and compile the project. Is this approach applicable to every APK file ? If we aim to make **very little** or **no modifications** in the java source code, does this approach work for every APK file? If not, what is the main reason?

As another question, i remember i read somewhere (can not find it now) that said converting *dex* to *jar* (with tools such as **dex2jar**) or decompiling dex to java (with tools such as **JADX**) is somehow lossy and causes information loss. Is there any such concept?

I ask this questions for educational purposes and i'm not aiming to do anything illegal.

Comment: In my experience, you can't rely on most decompilers to produce actual recompilable code, for anything but the most trivial code.

Comment: Converting a dex back to a jar shouldn't be lossy. After all, that code likely started life as a jar to begin with. Although I can't say with confidence that dex2jar specifically isn't lossless.

Comment: Although I might be a tiny bit biased, I think you would be better off disassembling the apk and modifying the bytecode, or using something like dexlib2 to modify the bytecode programatically.

Comment: @JesusFreke Yes, i've seen some examples of how to edit dex bytecodes to make some small changes but it gets complicated for big ones. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: @JesusFreke I think both jar -> dex and dex -> jar are lossy due to the subtle differences between the formats. For example, dex has no `multianewarray`, so array creation has to be desugared.

Comment: @Antimony I defer to your expertise. Having written such a tool yourself, you would know better than me :)